g++ works but g++-14 produces a lot of errors on macOS
I want to run g++-14 which I installed through brew install gcc so I can use the most up to date version of C++, but after installing I get a lot of errors when trying to compile code.
All the errors are way too long to copy here, but the last few are
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk/usr/include/malloc/_malloc_type.h:66:1: error: '__API_UNAVAILABLE3' does not name a type
   66 | _MALLOC_TYPE_AVAILABILITY void *malloc_type_zone_memalign(malloc_zone_t *zone, size_t alignment, size_t size, malloc_type_id_t type_id) __result_use_check __alloc_size(3);
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:182:1: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
  182 | __API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.0)) __IOS_PROHIBITED
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:220:56: error: expected initializer before '__API_AVAILABLE2'
  220 | int ptsname_r(int fildes, char *buffer, size_t buflen) __API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.13.4), ios(11.3), tvos(11.3), watchos(4.3));
      |                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:351:9: error: expected initializer before '__API_AVAILABLE2'
  351 |         __API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.15), ios(13.0), tvos(13.0), watchos(6.0));
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:359:9: error: expected initializer before '__API_AVAILABLE2'
  359 |         __API_AVAILABLE(macos(11.0), ios(14.0), tvos(14.0), watchos(7.0));
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0/include/c++/14/cstdlib:173:11: error: 'system' has not been declared in '::'
  173 |   using ::system;
      |           ^~~~~~

Someone asked what the first few errors are. I think they get cut off in the terminal (I can't scroll up all the way to the g++-14 command I wrote) but the first few that are still shown are
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0/lib/gcc/current/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin23/14/include-fixed/AvailabilityInternal.h:254:13: note: macro "__API_AVAILABLE0" defined here
  254 |     #define __API_AVAILABLE0(arg0) __API_A(arg0)
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:358:38: error: macro "__API_AVAILABLE0" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
  358 | __API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.4), ios(2.0))
      |                                      ^
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0/lib/gcc/current/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin23/14/include-fixed/AvailabilityInternal.h:254:13: note: macro "__API_AVAILABLE0" defined here
  254 |     #define __API_AVAILABLE0(arg0) __API_A(arg0)
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:361:38: error: macro "__API_AVAILABLE0" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
  361 | __API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.4), ios(2.0))

Running g++-14 --version outputs the following
g++-14 (Homebrew GCC 14.1.0) 14.1.0
Copyright (C) 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Edit:
I thought it would error on the absolute minimum program but it seems to be an issue with #include <iostream>
Specifically this program errors:
#include <iostream>

int main() {}


The compiler usually gets fairly confused after errors, "last few errors" is unlikely to be helpful if there are many preceding errors, try including "first few" instead.

Also, please show the code you are trying to compile. Try to  create a [mre].

@heapunderrun Thanks. It seems to be a problem with #include <iostream>. I edited the question

Why do you need to install gcc to use C++14 when Apple clang supports C++20?

@user1139069 because I'm a noob. That actually works, thanks

The issue has been resolved. Apple uses a non-standard location for the attributes, which is unsupported by GCC. However, an adapted version for GCC 14.2 is now available that addresses this compatibility for macOS only. Updated packages are available also on Homebrew.
For more details refer to this closed GitHub issue:
https://github.com/iains/gcc-14-branch/issues/12
